# Microsoft Visual Basic - Access 2016 - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA so I have a very basic understand of it and currently having an issue when running the following code:

```
Sub arrayData()
Dim custnames() As Variant
Dim num As Integer, dbs As Database, InsertRecord As String
Dim CustId As Integer, num1 As Integer
Dim CustName As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
CustId = 0
For num1 = 0 To 30000
CustId = CustId + 1
custnames = Array("Michael", "Larry", "Jeff", "Liam", "Gavin", "Ron", "Trevor", "Lester", "Leon", "Garry")



num = Int((30000 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
CustName = custnames(num)

InsertRecord = "insert into CUSTOMER (Cust_No, Cust_Name) values (" & "'" & CustId & "'" & "," & "'" & CustName & "'" & ")"

dbs.Execute InsertRecord
Debug.Print CustId; CustName

Next

End Sub
```

An error pops up when I press run saying "Run-time error '9': subscript out of range and the debug highlights `CustName = custnames(num)`. The goal of this code is to fill in a table with 30,000 records.

Comment: You're selecting an index between 1 and 30000, but the array only has 10 elements. You should also move the array creation outside the loop - there's no reason to assign exactly the same array 30000 times.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. It would have shown you what was wrong here.

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an index between 1 and 30000, but the array only has 10 elements. You want to generate a random integer in a range, which is generally done as follows:

```
num = Int((UBound(custnames) - LBound(custnames) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(custnames))
```

Since you know lower bound is 0:

```
num = Int((UBound(custnames) + 1) * Rnd)
```

As @Comintern noted, you should also move the array creation outside the loop.

Comment: No Problem. Welcome to SO.